# Need a box inside the graph that counts the LHS and RHS dots using matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matplotlib, graph

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num1 = 30
num3 = [4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999]
num2 = []
for i in range (len(num3)):
    num2.append(random.randrange(0,45))
print(num2)

plt.axvline(num1,0,color="r")
plt.scatter(num2, num3)
```

The code runs fine. There is no problem with it. I want to know how to get the box with exactly what it says from the following image:

[image]

Once you run the code, you will see a similar image without the box. The dots on the red line are considered to be in RHS. I made this graph using excel to show what I want. And, you can only use matplotlib.

I will probably need the code below for count

```
LHS_count = 0
for value in num2:
    if value < num1:
        LHS_count += 1
        print(LHS_count)
RHS_count = 0
for value in num2:
    if value >= num1:
        RHS_count += 1
        print(RHS_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use numpy for something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vl_pos = 30
y = np.array([4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999])

x = np.random.random(y.shape) * 45

lhs = (x < vl_pos).sum()
rhs = (x >= vl_pos).sum()
lhs,rhs

txt = ("lhs: %s\n"
      "rhs: %s"%(lhs,rhs))

f,a = plt.subplots()
a.axvline(vl_pos,color="r")
a.scatter(x, y)
bbox =dict(facecolor = 'w')
a.text(0.8, 0.8, txt, bbox = bbox, transform = a.transAxes)
```

Comment: I can't use numpy because the original code I have is based how matplotlib would be used if I want to graph. Changing that code is not possible. It is too much work.I would appreciate if you do it for me using matplotlib.

Comment: I don't quite understand. In my example the plotting is done using matplotlib. Numpy is used to process the data. Since numpy is a dependency of matplotlib you should have it on your system.